# ReactNative :Local images do not work with FlatList in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to build React-Native app and I have 4 images inside the project and I'm trying to display them through Flatlist. I put the image link into an array. I try to retrieve the images through the Render item, but it shows me this error
What am I doing wrong? What is the solution?

my array

```
const categoryData = [
    {
      title: 'middle east food',
      image: '../assets/image/category1.png',
      ALIAS: 'mediterranean, All',
    },
    {
      title: 'mexican food',
      image: '../assets/image/category2.jpg',
      ALIAS: 'easternmexican',
    },
    {
      title: 'Spanish Food',
      image: '../assets/image/category3.png',
      ALIAS: 'spanish, All',
    },
    {
      title: 'Turkish Food',
      image: '../assets/image/category4.jpg',
      ALIAS: 'turkish, All',
    },
  ];
```

flatListCode

```
<FlatList
            horizontal
            data={categoryData}
            renderItem={({item}) => (
              <Pressable>
                <Image source={require(item.image)}/>
                <Text>{item.title}</Text>
              </Pressable>
            )}
          />
```

error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuNli.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing the path as data, You can pass arrow function which renders the Image Component.

```
  const categoryData = [
    {
      title: 'middle east food',
      image: () => <Image source={require('../assets/image/category1.png')} />,
      ALIAS: 'mediterranean, All',
    },
    {
      title: 'mexican food',
      image: () => <Image source={require('../assets/image/category2.png')} />,
      ALIAS: 'easternmexican',
    },
    {
      title: 'Spanish Food',
      image: () => <Image source={require('../assets/image/category3.png')} />,
      ALIAS: 'spanish, All',
    },
    {
      title: 'Turkish Food',
      image: () => <Image source={require('../assets/image/category4.png')} />,
      ALIAS: 'turkish, All',
    },
  ];
```

And Then Simply pass the categoryData to the data prop of FlatList.
Also just call the {item.image()}

```
<FlatList
      horizontal
      data={categoryData}
      renderItem={({item}) => {
        return (
          <Pressable>
            {item.image()}
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
          </Pressable>
        );
      }}
    />
```

**This will Definitely solve your problem mate !**

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
  const categoryData = [
    {
      title: 'middle east food',
      image: require('../assets/image/category1.png'),
      ALIAS: 'mediterranean, All',
    },
    {
      title: 'mexican food',
      image: require('../assets/image/category2.jpg'),
      ALIAS: 'easternmexican',
    },
    {
      title: 'Spanish Food',
      image: require('../assets/image/category3.png'),
      ALIAS: 'spanish, All',
    },
    {
      title: 'Turkish Food',
      image: require('../assets/image/category4.jpg'),
      ALIAS: 'turkish, All',
    },
  ]; 




 <FlatList
                horizontal
                data={categoryData}
                renderItem={({item}) => (
                  <Pressable>
                    <Image
                      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator
                      resizeMode="stretch"
                      style={[
                        styles.categoryImg,
                        {width: width / 2.25, height: width / 2.25},
                      ]}
                      source={item.image}
                    />
```